# treeview - first node appears/displayed under root

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a form, button and treeview. I Start by adding a root node to my treeview. When the button is pressed it adds a node to the root but displays like this...

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Note, selecting the root node fixes the issue.

From class.cs ...

```
    Explorer explorer = new Explorer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        explorer.init(this.tree);
    }
```

From Explorer.cs ...

```
    private TreeView tree;
    private RootNode root;

    public Explorer()
    {
        root = new RootNode();
    }

    public void init(TreeView tree)
    {
        this.tree = tree;
        tree.LabelEdit = true;
        tree.Nodes.Add(root);
        tree.AfterLabelEdit += this.AfterLabelEdit;
    }
```

And the root node...

```
public class RootNode : TreeNode
{
    public RootNode()
    {
        this.Name = "main";
        this.Text = "Main";
    }

    // This method called by the button click handler
    public void AddTestCase()
    {
        var newNode = new TestCaseNode();
        newNode.Text = "New testcase";
        this.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        this.TreeView.Select();
        newNode.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does any of your classes set Font or do Owner-Drawing?

Comment: no, I haven't got round to that. Literally just trying to get a treeview up and running before I attempt to start playing.

Comment: _selecting the root node fixes the issue_ seems like a painting bug to me. Does it still happen if you comment out the newNode.BeginEdit(); ?

Comment: well... technically, no, because the tree is collapsed by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a quick look through the methods and added `newNode.EnsureVisible()`. That's fixed my problem.